# Getting monitoring metrics from Kafka application

Tags: apache-kafka

Beside some basic monitoring metrics like CPU , memory and network usage. Is there anyway that I can actually monitor the running Kafka application, such as number of messages in/out, stream throughput, stream size ...?

Thank you.

Comment: I upvoted amethystic answer (Kafka's built-in metrics that you can use to monitor your cluster or your applications that use the cluster).  There are also free/open source tools like https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager as well as commercial tools such as Confluent's Control Center for Kafka (https://www.confluent.io/product/control-center/).

Comment: https://medium.com/@giorgosmyrianthous/overview-of-ui-monitoring-tools-for-apache-kafka-clusters-9ca516c165bd

Answer (score 2):

Kafka offers various metrics reporting in both the server and the client. See [the Monitoring document](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#monitoring) for details.